# Generality of the Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

According to the Schrödinger equation
$$i \hbar \frac{d}{d t}\Psi(t) = H\Psi(t) \tag 1,$$
the transformation $U_t:\mathcal H\to \mathcal H: \Psi\mapsto \Psi(t)=e^{-itH}\Psi$ for every $t\in\mathbb R$ is a unitary transformation of the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, and since from this equation,

$$U_tU_s=U_{t+s}\tag 2,$$
the mapping, $t\mapsto U_t$ it is a one-parameter subgroup of the unitary group.

Starting from the other direction, if we suppose that the evolution of the states is a one-parameter subgroup of the unitary group, Stone's theorem yields (1).

But, since quantum mechanical states are not elements of $\mathcal H$, but they are elements of the projective Hilbert space $\mathcal P(\mathcal H)$, time evolution isn't a one-parameter subgroup of the unitary group, but it is a one-parameter subgroup of the projective unitary group, that is, by Wigner's theorem, instead of (2), only
$$U_tU_s=\omega(t,s)U_{t+s}\tag 3$$
must hold, where $\omega(t,s)$ is a complex number of modulus $1$ depending on $t$ and $s$.

From (2), Stone's theorem yields (1), but from (3), what theorem yields what?

Comment: $U(1)$ has the second Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomology group trivial, hence by Bargmann's theorem, you can choose the phase as $+1$.

Comment: @DanielC Could you expand this to a complete Answer?

Comment: @DanielC Are you sure that the cohomology of $U(1)$ is relevant, not the cohomology of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes, the cohomology group of the Lie algebra of U(1).

Comment: This is a cocycle in the cohomology of the (additive) group $\mathbb R$, not one in the lie algebra cohomology of anything.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, did yo mean something like I wrote in my Answer?

Comment: @mma, yup! ${}{}$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez But I'm not satisfied with my explanation, on one hand, because of my injectivity assumption and on the other hand, because I used the cohomology of $S'$ instead of the cohomology of $\mathbb R$. How do I know that $\omega$ is a cocycle of the extension of the group $\mathbb R$ by $U(1)$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two theorems relevant here. The former proves that actually, under natural hypotheses, the multipliers $\omega$ can be removed and one can safely apply the Stone theorem. This theorem is an immediate corollary of the Bargmann theorem as the Lie group $\mathbb{R}$  is (simply connected and) Abelian and its Lie algebra cohomology is trivial, or also can be directly proved (it was established by Wigner independently).

1. (Wigner-Bargmann) If $\mathbb{R}\ni t \mapsto U_t$ is a  projective-unitary (so there are your $\omega$) representation such that
   $|\langle \psi|U_t\phi\rangle|$ is a continuous function of $t$ for every choice of $\psi,\phi$ in the Hilbert space, then it is possible to re-arrange the multipliers $\omega$ (by multiplying the $U_t$ with suitable phases $U’_t:= e^{if(t)}U_t$) in order to obtain a strongly-continuos *properly unitary* representation.

The latter shows that, if the representation is unitary, continuity is almost automatic, since non Borel-measurable functions are really difficult to find.

2. (von Neumann) if $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto \langle \psi| U_t\phi\rangle$ is Borel measurable for every choice of $\psi,\phi$ of a separable Hilbert space where each $U_t$ acts as a unitary operator and the $U_t$ form a group representation of $\mathbb{R}$, then $t\to U_t$ is strongly continuous. So we can apply  the Stone theorem.

Comment: Could you please add a reference to this Wigner-Bargmann theorem?

Comment: It is nothing but the celebrated Bargmann theorem applied to the Lie group $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The Bargmann theorem states that, for a simply connected finite-dimensional LIe group $G$,  $G \ni g \mapsto U_g$ is a projective-unitary representation which is also continuous in the sense I wrote above, then the representation can be transformed in a strongly-continuous properly unirtari rep of $G$ if a cohomological condition is true. This condition states that, if $\alpha: T_eG \times T_eG \to T_eG$ is antisymmetric map satisfying a sort of Jacobi condition then it has the form $\alpha(g,g')= \beta([g,g'])$, for some linear map $\beta$.

Comment: If $G= \mathbb{R}$ all maps $\alpha$ are the zero map, so every thing is trivial. Above $T_eG$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ and $[,]$ its Lie bracket. The Jacobi condition is $\alpha([g,g'], g'') +$ cyclic permutations $=0$.

Comment: However, Wigner established an independent proof of the case $G=\mathbb{R}$. You may find all these things **for instance** in my books *Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics* (2018?) 2nd edition Springer and  *Foundamental Mathematical Structures of Quantum Theory* (2019) Springer. However those results are quite famous and you can find them (and generalisations) in several modern textbooks on related subgects.

Comment: I see now, thanks.  

- Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics, p. 736, Theorem 12.72 (Bargmann) 

- Fundamental Mathematical Structures of Quantum Theory, p. 265, Theorem 7.14 (Bargmann’s Criterion)

- Bargmann: On Unitary Ray Representations of Continuous Groups, p. 13 

THEOREM 3.2. Any continuous ray representation Ur of a connected and simply connected group G with a local factor equivalent to 1 is induced by a strongly con- tinuous unitary representation Ur of G.